# Making changes to Case Effective Date

Tags: case, fields, update

I am attempting to use workbench to update the Effective Date of several cases and it's giving me the error "'7/8/2020' is not a valid value for the type xsd:date."

Updating Object Type: Case

Mapped Fields:
ID
Effective_Date__c

What value should I be placing for the Effective Date field? (since its not accepting the MM/DD/YYYY format)

Answer (score 1):

Use YYYY-MM-DD i.e 2020-07-08.

Below are the Date field acceptable formats.

YYYY-MM-DD, YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss, YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ, YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ

[Date formats](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000325035&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)